# Rotating magnetic field discrepancy

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor, phasor, magnetic-flux

This may be a noob question

Lets consider a balanced 3 phase supply namely

\begin{align}
R&= V \sin(x)\\
Y&= V \sin(x-120)\\
B&= V \sin(x+120)
\end{align}

At a neutral point we would say that the resultant voltage=0 as R+Y+B=0

However lets consider the magnetic flux produced by each phase in a 2 pole stator with the equations same as above (consider V to be maximum flux). 
If we go by the same logic then the net flux should also be zero but it isnt.
Quick research says that we should use vectors or the complex notation to find the resultant flux. Why do I encounter this discrepancy?

Comment: The time averaged net flux will be zero.

Comment: but in voltage isn't the voltage at every single instant zero?

Comment: At the neutral point but not spatially.